# When using a VPN is the device DNS cache still written to?

Tags: web-browser, vpn, dns

When I am using ProtonVPN, does the VPN server run DNS resolution upon receiving the request, [similar to a Tor exit node](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-does-tor-route-dns-requests/26), thereby bypassing the device's DNS cache?

Or do my browser's DNS queries still write to the device DNS cache? And if they are written locally, is there a way to prevent this on different operating systems in order to minimise logging of network activity (short of running Tails/Qubes/whatever)?

Comment: Note that in the linked question, they're talking about a Tor ***client***. That means the client is specially designed to use Tor in that way from the browser on down the stack. A VPN "client" just connects you to the virtual network. You use a normal browser.